# Moment Timezone JS return true date conversion on development but return incorrect in production

Tags: node.js, momentjs, moment-timezone

I made a time conversion between original time 'Asia/Jakarta' (GMT+7) and 'Asia/Tokyo' (JST). The actual difference is 2 hours (GMT+7 00:00, JST 02:00) In development, it return with true value like this:

```
24 Januari 2020, 00:00 GMT+7 
24 Januari 2020, 02:00 JST
```

But when it uploaded to production server (the server was placed at NY, US), the conversion was incorrect. Returning

```
24 Januari 2020, 00:00 GMT+7 
24 Januari 2020, 09:00 JST
```

I thought that I need to set Default Timezone, but the error was getting worse. And got

```
25 Januari 2020, 07:00 GMT+7
25 Januari 2020, 09:00 JST
```

Here's the code that I write:

```js
// calling the modules
const moment = require('moment');
const momentTz = require('moment-timezone');

//... initializing code

moment.locale('id');
moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Jakarta');
// args[1] = '24/01'
// args[2] = '00:00'
      try {
        const timeFormat = 'Do MMMM YYYY, HH:mm';
        const dateSplit = args[1].split('/');
        const date =
          dateSplit[1] + '/' + dateSplit[0] + '/' + moment().format('YYYY');
        const dateTime = Date.parse(`${date} ${args[2]}`);
        const livestreamDateTime = moment(dateTime).format(timeFormat);
        const livestreamDateTimeJapan = momentTz
          .tz(dateTime, 'Asia/Tokyo')
          .format(timeFormat);
        const vliverFirstName = args[0].toLowerCase();
        const vData = vliver[vliverFirstName];
        const youtubeId = args[3];
// ...
// ... showing the output and catching error underneath
```

The date I got from typing user input. So when user type `24/01 00:00`, it says that the date is `24 January 2020 00:00 GMT+7`

**EDIT:** I've checked the production server date. It shows my GMT+7 Timezone.

[image: Server Time and Time]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue.

Because the time difference is actually 2 hours. And what I need to do is comparing 2 Time zones only, so what I need to do is to add the input date and time by 2 hours. And also not set the Default Time zone

```
const date = dateSplit[1] + '/' + dateSplit[0] + '/' + moment().format('YYYY');
const dateTime = Date.parse(`${date} ${args[2]}`);
const livestreamDateTime = moment(dateTime).format(timeFormat);
const livestreamDateTimeJapan = moment(dateTime)
  .add(2, 'hours')
  .format(timeFormat);
```

It still returns as same timezone. But I think that's not a big deal because I hide the timezone and replace it with hard coded string.